# What's the difference between non-primitive and primitive in virtual machine implementation?

Tags: virtual-machine, forth

I see something in the article *[Threaded Code](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/threaded-code.html)*:

> Traditionally Forth is implemented using indirect threading. Therefore, direct threaded Forth implementations have much in common with indirect threaded implementations: **Non-primitives** have a code field, but it now contains a jump to the code instead of its address. On most processors this jump costs more time than the additional load of indirect threading, so direct threading only pays off when **primitives** are executed. The resulting speedup is 2%-8% on the 486.

So, what's the difference between "non-primitive" and "primitive" which are referred to in the above text?

Comment: From the linked page: *"The virtual machine code is now represented by a sequence of code field addresses, not code addresses. Simple virtual machine instructions (primitives) are typically represented like this:"*

Answer (score 1):

Non-primitives are defined in terms of other Forth words. Primitives are in native code for the target platform.

Traditionally, most target platforms had no issues with mixing code and data, so the Forth dictionary would be one single data structure starting with primitives at the top, while later words would be defined as non-primitives.

A typical word definition would have a header, contain the name of the word, a link to the previous word in the dictionary (creating a linked list), followed by the code field and the actual definition.

Check out http://www.forth.org/fig-forth/contents.html for several examples.

From the 6502 definition of `-`, starting with the code field:

```
.WORD DOCOL
.WORD MINUS
.WORD PLUS
.WORD SEMIS
```

This is literally the compilation of the code part of `: - MINUS + ;`

And this is the definition of the primitive `MINUS`:

```
.WORD *+2
SEC
TYA
SBC 0,X
STA 0,X
TYA
SBC 1,X
STA l , X
JMP NEXT
```

The first starts with the address of `DOCOL`, while the next just refers to the native code 2 bytes up.

In this case, `MINUS` is the primitive, but it still involves the indirect jump through the address in the first two bytes. The threaded interpreter is present in the form of `DOCOL` and `SEMIS`.

Answer (score 1):

By the mentioned article, a primitive is a simple virtual machine instruction. But it doesn't clear enough: what instruction is simple and what isn't.

By the [terms definitions](https://forth-standard.org/standard/notation), a *Forth definition* is a Forth execution procedure compiled into the dictionary. So, by the "*definition*" term we mean a *Forth definition*.

For simplicity, let's consider further only the definitions that are identified by an execution token.

Conceptually, the description of such definition in the dictionary has the header (possibly empty) and the body. The body *describes* the execution semantics in some binary code format  (i.e., a *binary language*). The header (if any) can determine the code format of the body, when several formats are used.

The variants of [threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) are examples of a binary code format.

Usually a definition is described via other definitions (and literals). But it's impossible to describe all definitions in a Forth system in this way. Some definitions will be inevitably described without any references to other definitions. These definitions are described in the binary code of the underlying machine or CPU.

So, a primitive is a definition that is described in the code of the underlying machine.

Note that primitives **can** use other definitions, but only primitives can be described even without other definitions.

In some Forth system implementations all definitions are primitives in this sense — e.g., when subroutine-threaded code is used (actually, this code is quasi threaded).